# How uploading data to a CDN work?

Tags: file-upload, image-uploading, cdn

I didn't use a cdn myself but I'm really curious on how data gets uploaded to them. Suppose a user uploads an image to a cdn pop, is that image stored only on that one cdn pop? But if so if user moves away and uses another cdn pop the image will not be availble?
Or what if another user wants that image but that cdn pop is far away from her/him?
Otherwise the image needs to be uploaded on hundreds of cdn pops, which takes lot of bandwidth. Thus an image of 10kb could take tens of megabytes of your available bandwidth/month.
This doesn't make lots of sense to me.
Can anybody clear this up ?

Comment: You should start by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Comment: I gave a look to it and it seems that there is no mention of what I asked.

Comment: But yes it is. F.e. it says right there, _“Here content (potentially multiple copies) may exist on several servers. When a user makes a request to a CDN hostname, DNS will resolve to an optimized server (based on location, availability, cost, and other metrics) and that server will handle the request.”_ And your _“doesn’t make sense to me”_ seems to stem from a lack of understanding what CDNs do and what their purpose is – and that’s what the article explains.

Comment: But how many copies? If there are 500 of them, 10 copies? 20? This means that a 10k image will eat 100k+? Or it'll eat only 10k even if multiple copies are spread over them?

Comment: The exact numbers will vary between CDNs, but to serve an asset from a location close to the user needs multiple copies around the globe of course. And whether your 10k file needs 5 or 10MB doesn’t matter, because space is cheap.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Thus using CDNs with ~20 POPs seems to be best if there's gonna lots of images and you want it to be cheap(since the max number of CDN POPs to which content is spread is 20).

Comment: No, I didn’t say any specific number. Depending on the specific purpose of the CDN those numbers might vary largely. And it might even be dynamic, f.e. based on how frequently an asset gets requested, where from etc.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways you can serve data from most CDNs:

1. **Using a pull zone:** This pulls existing content from your origin server and caches it on the CDN's PoPs
2. **Using a push zone:** You manually upload content to the CDNs storage cluster and from there the content gets distributed to the CDN's PoPs.

To answer your other questions:

Asset caching is based on where the visitor is requesting the asset from. If the visitor is in Australia and the CDN has a PoP in Australia then the asset will be cached there. However, if another user requests the same as from Germany, and the CDN has a server in Germany then the asset will be cached there as well.

The asset will always be delivered from the nearest available PoP. If the PoP doesn't have the requested asset, it will ask the server and then cache the asset so that it can be delivered faster to the next requester.

To learn more about how CDNs work and what they entail, I'd recommend taking a read through this guide: https://www.keycdn.com/what-is-a-cdn

Comment: In other words about pull zone: user uploads file to your server, so that file resides there (as if you were not using CDN), but when you use one, the only thing that changes is file URL - it points to cdn, not to your server. If file don't exist in CDN, then it will be pulled from your server and served from CDN. (this answer finally let me understand it)

Comment: If the assets are stored in the Australian PoP, for example, do these assets automatically get copied over to the other PoP's globally so that the cache is ready to be served in other destinations? Or does the user from another location have to request in order to cache the assets on the other PoP (for example in Germany)? Sorry for my silly question,  I am very new to CDN technology :)