# How do you create a javascript source src="" script file?

Tags: javascript, html, shared-libraries

I'm looking to creating a javascript file where I can use in my projects or have other people source in theirs. For example when you source your project in the script tag:

```
<script src='https://mycoolwebsite.com/awesome-script.js'></script>
```

Also, what type would this be? type='text/javascript' or type='application/javascript'

Let's say i want to store something in the cookie just to test this out

awesome-script.js

```
function saveCookie() {
  localStorage.setItem('cookie', 'monster')
}
```

The end result is when this script is used - {'cookie': 'monster'} is stored in the users cookies

Is this more complicated than it sounds? Is there a structure I have to follow to achieve this?

Perhaps this is more under the category of creating your own javascript library. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

No need for type at all. Only in the olden days where IE could use VBScript was it necessary to include type on JS files and only if there actually was a VBScript file there.

Nowadays this only type you might need on a JS file is ["module"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) but only if it IS a module. Just save a UTF8 file on [github](https://github.com/) for example if you want to share it. Make sure it has a lot of comments and a [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) version without any comments.

If it becomes really popular, you could host it on a [CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521419/how-uploading-data-to-a-cdn-work)